# How can i check if there is a letter multiple times in a string and identify each of these occurances?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a working hangman and it's working well except for words that have repeated letters, it is only identifying the first instance and ignoring all others
(`jafoi` is to check if the letter has already been inserted before).

```
p=input("insert letter")
 if p in x and p not in jafoi: 
  jafoi.append(p)
  print("ya! letter"+str((x.index(p))+1))
```

I am using the code below to illustrate the hangman, and even though `count(p)` recognizes more than one instance of the letter the code only illustrates the first instance even if i use a `for i in range(x.count(p):`

```
graph=[]
for i in range(xx):
  graph.append("_")
graph[x.index(p)]=p
  print(graph)
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: If you want to know how many times a particular character occurs in a string then use *str.count()* That's exactly what it's for

Answer (score 0):

```
[i for i, l in enumerate(word) if l == letter]
```

This is a one-line method to get a list of indexes. The full outwritten version would be:

```
indexes = []
  for i, l in enumerate(word):
    if l == letter:
      indexes.append(i)
  return indexes
```

Hope this helps. Lars!

Comment: "words cannot describe how thankful I am, i will name a variable Lars to honor you.

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` from the built-in `collections` module may be useful for your project:

```
from collections import Counter

out = Counter("hangman")

# This looks like:
print(out)

# Say we just want values with more than one:
print({k:v for k, v in out.items() if v > 1})

# Say you want to remove a letter:
out.subtract('n')
print(out)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'a': 2, 'n': 2, 'h': 1, 'g': 1, 'm': 1})

{'a': 2, 'n': 2}

# You can see our count of "n" went down by one.
Counter({'a': 2, 'h': 1, 'n': 1, 'g': 1, 'm': 1})
```